# From a theoretical standpoint, is anything better than BitTorrent for file distribution?

Tags: file-transfer, bittorrent

If I close my eyes hard enough, I can remember the days when p2p meant one-to-one by default.

Despite it being established for nearly a decade, I still marvel at the quantum leap that is torrent distribution.

Which makes me wonder, and Wikipedia doesn't address this, can there be a better way? I'm talking on a theoretical basis here... is anything possibly faster than the torrent method for distributing files to a massive network? Or has Bram Cohen basically *won the Internetz*?

*(Feel free to relocate this to a different exchange if it doesn't fit best here...)*

Comment: What is "better" for you? What kind of criteria you are using? The best way in my eyes is to get everything burned on a DVD and sent around by post -- why not?

Comment: You have to specifiy your criteria for "better": Reliability, security, speed or robustness of file data? @AlexanderGalkin: Dont you think, this would be a little bit expensive over time? ;)

Comment: @PaddyG: I don't care, it is just **better** for me to have it that way :)

Comment: Better, (in the question) is defined as **faster**. The paper linked in the accepted answer, (from 2005) proposes a possible increase to efficiency, but due to the "good enough" inertia of the existing protocol, I doubt that it would be implemented in the existing protocol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick research paper I found online points out in the introduction some reasons why BitTorrent is so successful compared to other P2P architectures including the Tit-For-Tat (TFT) mechanism where by nodes/users preferable upload more to nodes/user that they can download from (this is the hope anyway).  There are many other reasons why BitTorrent is so popular including: reliability due it's distributed nature (much like the internet itself); Speed and Scalability.

However I think theoretically it's not weather something is going to be better than BitTorrent but instead as this research paper proves there can be improvements made:
[Analyzing and Improving BitTorrent Performance](https://web.archive.org/web/20170706073104/http://www.ece.ucdavis.edu/~chuah/classes/EEC274/refs/06BHP-BT-infocom.pdf)

Hope this helps and if you find any research papers post them back please

Answer (score -2):

Bittorrent is actuallually a rather primitive protocol, and a huge step backwards from even eDonkey. In the beginning it was nothing more than a distributed FTP-equivalent, and they even now barely added the most important features back in.

Key things were/are:

- Actually being decentralized. (Trackers were the centralized aspect. eDonkey failed in that too, but fixed it earlier than BitTorrent.)
- No built-in search. (Even Napster already had a search function. Catalog websites don’t count, as they are yet another centralized point of failure.)
- No encryption. (Has partially been fixed, but not in a truly trustworthy way.)
- No anonymization. (This point still fully stands. Darknet protocols, except for TOR, are a better choice.)

There are much better much older protocols out there. Hell, when it came out, basically *anything* apart from FTP was vastly superior.

BitTorrent only became successful due to its speed. Which it “achieved” by throwing out nearly the whole point of p2p file sharing. Not a feat at all. Sure my car is faster, if it throws out any interest in comfort, safety or fuel efficiency. :)

But BitTorrent was never intended for file sharing anyway. It was literally intended to replace FTP/HTTP for downloads when the site couldn’t deliver the required bandwidth. And for nothing else.
For that it is OK. But otherwise it is the Windows ME of file sharing: A core designed for a much much simpler world, abused way past its design specs, with the features that are standard in all other systems badly tacked on.

Comment: It feels like you argument is equivalent to, "Horses are better than cars because you can't eat a car." Your answer confuses protocol with application and doesn't answer the question. Do you know of anything **theoretically** better? (Not "Do you miss Limewire? "Press F to pay respects...")